# Conversion of JPEG-filenames by using metadata in java

Tags: java, metadata, jpeg, exif

I need to write a little tool in JAVA that scans all JPEG-files in a given directory and renames them to the format YYYY-MM-DD hh:ss  (Year-Month-Day Hour-Second). I have to use the metadata in the JPEG-files to determine the timestamp / new filename.
I already know Java but i'm new to writing working tools so i'd like to know how you guys would proceed step-by-step in order to solve this task since i'm kind of lost and don't know where to begin.
I'm also new to stackoverflow so if my question is too vague or anything else feel free to tell me.

Comment: Please have a look at [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Are you sure all your JPEGs will contain timestamps (ie. be EXIF JPEGs), and you absolutely need to use that? If not, it would be a lot easier to just use the file system's creation/modification timestamp...

Comment: To access metadata in images you may like to try using my [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor) library.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code so I will give you the guide:

First you will need to list files in a folder using [listfiles()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29) from the java.io.File class.

Then you will need to get the file extension which is ".JPEG" you do this by using

[FilenameUtils.getExtension](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getExtension%28java.lang.String%29) from [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/)

Or you can use [endsWith()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_endswith) Method, which gets the 'MIME' type of the files. Then to rename, you use:

[Java.io.File.renameTo()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/file_renameto)

These are the steps you are looking for.